# Change variable based on breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change a variable based on breakpoints?

The variable is first set on this script

```
    $('#carousel-example').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    /*
        CC 2.0 License Iatek LLC 2018 - Attribution required
    */
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 5;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
 
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And I'm trying to change the variables by placing a script on the body... this is probably criminal or not even possible, but I'm not a programmer lol

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var bodyWidth = $('body').width(); 

    if(bodyWidth > 320 && bodyWidth < 400) {
        var totalItems = $(‘.carousel-item’).length;
    var itemsPerSlide = totalItems – 3;
    }

    if(bodyWidth > 768 && bodyWidth < 1024) {
        var itemsPerSlide = 5;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
    }

    if(bodyWidth > 1224) {
        var itemsPerSlide = 5;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length; 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you are using [bootstraps carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/#methods) and you want to control how many slides on each responsive break point.

I use bootstrap all time, and when ever I need a carousel, I use [Ken Wheelers Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider. Super easy to use, utilises jQuery which you already have and has awesome responsive break point functionality plus other cool options.

Check out this example and see my comments in the code...

```js
// bootstrap default break points constant variable object
const breakpoint = {

  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576,

  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768,

  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992,

  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200

};

// carousel example slick slider
$('#carousel-example').slick({
  
  // settings from now are mobile first
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  draggable: true,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  speed: 1000,
  mobileFirst: true,
  
  // 2 slides to show/scroll (on mobile)
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  
  // begin responsive settings
  responsive: [{
  
      // overrides or new settings at breakpoint sm and up
      breakpoint: breakpoint.sm,
      settings: {

        // show carousel controls (override) 
        arrows: true,
        
        // 3 slides to show/scroll (overrides)
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      }
    },
    {
    
      // overrides or new settings at breakpoint md and up
      breakpoint: breakpoint.md,
      settings: {
      
        // show carousel controls (override) 
        arrows: true,
        
        // 4 slides to show/scroll (overrides) 
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4
      }
    },
    {
    
      // overrides or new settings at breakpoint lg and up
      breakpoint: breakpoint.lg,
      settings: {
      
        // show carousel controls (override) 
        arrows: true,
        
        // 5 slides to show/scroll (overrides) 
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5
      }
    },
    {
    
      // overrides or new settings at breakpoint xl (add more custom breakpoints too breakpoint constant variable
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xl,
      settings: {
      
        // show carousel controls (override) 
        arrows: true,
        
        // 6 slides to show/scroll (overrides) 
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 6
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
/* carousel example css to be hidden until initialized */

#carousel-example {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#carousel-example.slick-initialized {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  overflow: initial;
}


/* carousel example css to emulate boostraps grid so each slide behaves like a column inside a row, but the slide "column" widths are handled by slicks responsive settings */

#carousel-example .slick-list {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

#carousel-example .slick-list:before,
#carousel-example .slick-list:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff; /* set this to your page background color */
}

#carousel-example .slick-list:before {
  left: 0;
  /* background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); */
}

#carousel-example .slick-list:after {
  right: 0;
  /* background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); */
}

#carousel-example .slick-slide {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

#carousel-example .slick-slide:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* carousel example css to emulate boostrap carousel controls */

#carousel-example .slick-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat 50%/100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 1000px;
  border: none;
}

#carousel-example .slick-arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#carousel-example .slick-prev {
  left: -15px;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23212529' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5L4.25 4l2.5-2.5L5.25 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

#carousel-example .slick-next {
  right: -15px;
  transform: translate(100%, -50%);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23212529' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}


/* carousel example css to emulate bootstrap carousels indicators */

#carousel-example .slick-dots {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  list-style: none;
}

#carousel-example .slick-dots LI {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #212529;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .6s ease;
}

#carousel-example .slick-dots LI.slick-active,
#carousel-example .slick-dots LI:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#carousel-example .slick-dots LI>BUTTON {
  display: none;
}


/* fix for demo overflow horizontal scrolling */

BODY {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- slick css -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- bootstrap container for demo -->
<div class="container py-3">

  <!-- carousel example slider -->
  <div id="carousel-example">

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris...</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris...</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris...</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris...</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/x7ZYW4i.png" class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris...</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EYTCssm.png" class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Article title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Ut sed ligula vel felis vulputate lobortis id eget mauris...</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>

<!-- jQuery and bootstrap 4 js bundle w/ popper.js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- slick jQuery min -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```